# Flutter web crash lines are incorrect

Tags: flutter-web

My flutter app is crashing and in the log I don't get the real lines of the crash.

It shows me the line of the crush in the `.dart.lib.js` file which is my file after it got converted to javascript.

Is there a way to make the logs show the real crash lines?.

My first file here is one before the last line of in the photo `user_repository.dart.lib.js:27937:31`

[image]

Comment: Hi, Have you figured this out? I am seeing the same issue.